# What are different strategies for showing that the spectral radius of a matrix is less than one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

I know I can bound the spectral radius of a matrix by a norm of the matrix. Are there other approaches? In my case, I have a positive square matrix J(v) that depends on some fixed parameters and the vector v that lives in the simplex (i.e., $v_i\geq0,\forall i$ and $\sum_i v_i =1$), and I need to show that $$\max_v \rho(J(v)) \leq 1.$$

Simulations reveal that this is true, but also that well known norms (i.e., infinity norm or spectral norm) don't give me the right bounds. Is proof by contradiction useful? I am going to leave this question vague because the details are somewhat complicated and probably not of much interest here, but suggestions and examples would be most welcomed.

Comment: How explicit are your matrices on which your upper bounds are not tight? It might help to reduce the set of maximizers $v$ to consider using, say, convexity properties of your parametrization

Comment: @A When you say that $J(v)$ is a "positive" matrix, does that mean that all of its entries are positive or is positive synonymous with "positive definite"?

Comment: @A If you mean the former, then the following might be useful: for any positive matrix $A$, there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal entries such that $\rho(A) = \|DAD^{-1}\|_\infty$

Comment: @A We have no way to answer a question like "is proof by contradiction useful?" without knowing more about the problem

Comment: @BenGrossmann $J(v)$ has all positive entries, thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have created a question with all the details of my particular problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4186355/165163  I fear it may be too specific to generate interest here -- perhaps there is a better way of asking this quuestion?

Comment: @md5 I have created a question with all the details of my particular problem here: math.stackexchange.com/q/4186355/165163 I fear it may be too specific to generate interest here -- perhaps there is a better way of asking this quuestion?